# Does influx-python's client have a precision config like the influx client does?

Tags: influxdb

I have millions of entries that are already in epoch ms format as longs.

I don't want to waste time converting to a string like "2016-..." if possible.

Does influx-python's InfluxDBClient have a precision arg, similar to how the native influx client allows -precision when it imports? I looked i github but didn't find it.

Or is the native client just converting everything into rfc3339 under the covers anyhow? I would think that the underlying wire protocol would want stamps as simple longs not strings.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar trouble. Its in documentation while writing points you can pass `time_precision` as parameter in the `write_point` function. If you are using series Helper look at

https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python/issues/502

Pull request I made. It helps in setting it in one place and not having to pass it everywhere. I opened up an issue for this.

https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python/issues/501